# Implement simple mutex in javascript

Tags: javascript, concurrency, mutex

I was asked to code mutex in JS in an interview.

Here's my attempt. It simulates the problem, but doesn't fix it

```
async function runTest10Times() {
  let count = 10;
  while (count > 0) {

    // Solution 1: await simulateConcurrencyProblem() 
    // add await to all async calls. That way the program will be synchronous.
    // However this defeats the purpose of parallelism.
    // This is not using mutex 

    simulateConcurrencyProblemFixedUsingMutex();
    // I want to run this program without await so that all functions can be started 
    // concurrently and use Mutex for updating counter variable.
    
    count--;
  }
}
```

```js
// Test Problem
let amount = 0;

const randomDelay = () => new Promise(resolve =>
  setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 100)
)

async function loadAmount() {
  await randomDelay();
  return amount;
}

async function saveAmount(value) {
  await randomDelay();
  return amount += value;
}

async function resetCounter() {
  amount = 0;
}
async function addFifty(value) {
  const amount = await loadAmount();
  await saveAmount(amount + 50);
}

async function addSixty(value) {
  const amount = await loadAmount();
  await saveAmount(amount + 60);
}

async function subtract20() {
  const amount = await loadAmount();
  await saveAmount(amount - 20);
}

// Solution
function createMutex() {
  let lockPromise = Promise.resolve();    // Initial state of promise is resolved
  let lockResolve;  // a resolver function that will be used to unlock the mutex

  return {
    lock: () => {     // call to protect a critical section from concurrent access.

      lockPromise = lockPromise.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          lockResolve = resolve;
        })
      })

      return lockPromise;    
      // When a lock is acquired, we return a resolver, which calls resolve function to release lock
    },

    unlock: () => {
      if(lockResolve) {
        lockResolve()
      }
      
    }
  }
}

const mutex = createMutex();

async function simulateConcurrencyProblemFixedUsingMutex() {
  // mutex.lock();   // Acquire the lock before accessing/modifying the counter
  await resetCounter();
  await addFifty();
  await addSixty();
  await subtract20();

  const amount = await loadAmount();
  console.log("Solved: Final amount is: " + amount);
  // mutex.unlock();
}


// Test Runner
async function runTest10Times() {
  let count = 10;
  while (count > 0) {
    await simulateConcurrencyProblemFixedUsingMutex();
    // Solution 1: await simulateConcurrencyProblem() 
    // add await to all async calls. That way the program will be synchronous.
    // However this defeats the purpose of parallelism.
    // This is not using mutex either
    
    count--;
  }
}

runTest10Times();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutex in JavaScript - does this look like a correct implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086688/mutex-in-javascript-does-this-look-like-a-correct-implementation)